# How do I respawn the rectangle after contact in a random location in Slick2D?

Tags: java, collision-detection, lwjgl, slick2d

Much like the critically acclaimed "Shower with your Dad Simulator 2015" I'm trying to write a program where the player runs into a rectangle, and then after- it the rectangle respawns in a random location on the map. I tried to do this by calling the render() method, but realized that (1) this would leave the last rectangle on the ground and (2) in the render() constructor, "g" isn't considered a valid argument for some reason. Here's my code for the Play class.

```
    public class Play extends BasicGameState 
{
    private Image player;
    private Shape castle;
    private Random randX, randY;
    private final int MAX_X = 730;
    private final int MAX_Y = 570;
    private int playerX = 400;
    private int playerY = 590;
    private int castleX, castleY;

    public Play(int state)
    {

    }

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException 
    {
        player = new Image("res/play.png");
        randX = new Random();
        randY = new Random();
        castleX = randX.nextInt(MAX_X);
        castleY = randY.nextInt(MAX_Y);
        castle = new Rectangle(castleX,castleY,70,70);
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException 
    {
        g.drawImage(player, playerX, playerY);
        g.setColor(new Color(0,255,0));
        g.fill(castle);
        g.draw(castle);
    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException 
    {
        Input input = gc.getInput();
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){playerY -= 1;}
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){playerY += 1;}
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){playerX -= 1;}
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){playerX += 1;}

        if(playerX == castle.getX())
        {
            /*try
            {
            this.render(gc, sbg, g);
            }
            catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}*/
        }
    }

    public int getID() 
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with some advice. Your init method is quite clear. So is your render at the moment. In your update method, you should never call render as it is called every cycle. Just for reference, remember that in Slick, a game is compose by two steps : the init that call your init method, the cycle that call every few milisecond render() and update(). What you update in cycle N will be applied on cycle N+1 (the difference is invisible for the player).

In order to test intersection between your castle and your player there is a formula to do it. Something like

```
 If( (Cx>Px && Cx<Px+Pw) && (Cy>Py && Cy<Py+Ph) || // Top left corner

 (Cx+Cw>Px && Cx+Cw<Px+Pw) && (Cy>Py && Cy<Py+Ph) || //top right corner

 (Cx>Px && Cx<Px+Pw) && (Cy+Ch>Py && Cy+Ch<Py+Ph) || // bottom left corner

 (Cx+Cw>Px && Cx+Cw<Px+Pw) && (Cy+Ch>Py && Cy+Ch<Py+Ph) ) //bottom right corner
```

With : Cx = castleX, Cy = castleY, Cw = castleWidth; and P for Player etc...

However doing this is quite annoying. You can still do it if you want to. But I prefer using Slick's power : [intersect](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/geom/Shape.html)!

Now, let's see how to make this castle move.

```
public class Play extends BasicGameState 
{
    private Image playerImage;
    private Rectangle playerRectangle;
    private Shape castle;
    private Random randX, randY;
    private final int MAX_X = 730;
    private final int MAX_Y = 570;
    private int playerX = 400;
    private int playerY = 590;
    private int castleX, castleY, castleWidth, castleHeight;

    public void init(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg) throws SlickException 
    {
        playerImage = new Image("res/play.png");
        playerRetangle = new Rectangle(playerX, playerY, playerImage.getWidth(), playerImage.getHeight());
        randX = new Random();
        randY = new Random();
        castleX = randX.nextInt(MAX_X);
        castleY = randY.nextInt(MAX_Y);
        castleWidth = 70;
        castleHeight = 70;
        castle = new Rectangle(castleX, castleY, castleWidth, castleHeight);
    }

    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException 
    {
        g.drawImage(playerImage, playerRectangle.getX(), playerRectangle.getY());
        g.setColor(new Color(0,255,0));
        g.fill(castle);
        g.draw(castle);
    }

    public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int delta) throws SlickException 
    {
        Input input = gc.getInput();


        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)){playerRectangle.setY(playerRectangle.getY() - 1;}
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)){playerRectangle.setY(playerRectangle.getY() + 1;}
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)){playerRectangle.setX(playerRectangle.getX() - 1;}
        if(input.isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)){playerRectangle.setX(playerRectangle.getX() + 1;}


        // use formula or intersect
        if(castle.intersects(playerRectangle)) {
            castleX = randX.nextInt(MAX_X);
            castleY = randY.nextInt(MAX_Y);
        }
    }
}
```

PS : to improve your code you should test your input in mousePressed overriden method. See: [mousePressed in BasicGameState](http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/state/BasicGameState.html)